unable to update to ubuntu 24 from ubuntu 22
Have Ubuntu 22 plus LinuxCNC on an HP envy h8-1534 tower computer with SSD drive. It does not alow update to Ubuntu 24. Ubuntu 22 was installed with a DVD, because our internet is terrible. Ubuntu 22 works great on this PC. When I tried a Ubuntu 24 USB flash drive it would not allow upgrading (button option grayed out)only slamming the entire Computer. Do I have to slam this PC to upgrade to 24? This is NOT a dual boot PC.

Please be precise & clear with details; you mention Ubuntu 22; so is this a Ubuntu Core 22 install? as the main Ubuntu releases are year.month in format. A Ubuntu 22.04 LTS system will allow upgrade to Ubuntu 24.04 LTS if fully upgraded & not too broken in regards adding/removing packages (esp. 3rd party), but the error messages on attempted upgrade will allow you to better understand problems. You only mention the 22 & 24 as if this is a snap only Core install (22.04 & 24.04 are available in Desktop & Server installs thus different installers are in play; 22 & 24 are Server only)

FYI:  You should strike, or hit / punch any electronic device (you say slam - which means strike/hit/punch) as it can only damage components, and won't have any positive results. There are still non-destructive re-install options for some 24.04 systems, but there are fewer for ubuntu-desktop-installer than ubiquity allowed for with 22.04 for example; but you mention 22 & 24 which don't use those installers anyway (your details are only vague)

@guiverc What I think they mean by slamming was probably mistranslated from something like wiping because the upgrade option is greyed out, their only option is to reinstall Ubuntu to the computer. Just a guess though.

See this related question on why the option was disabled. It should be noted that I think there was supposed to be a version released where the bug is fixed so it may depend on how old the image is on your USB device, not sure if that fix has been released yet or if you might need to download the "daily" release of 24.04 which should give you the utmost latest version instead of the last officially released version.

I think your other option would be to use sudo do-release-upgrade to do the upgrade instead of using an installation media. You mentioned internet speed problems so I could understand how either of these options might not be optimal but this would help you get around the problem you're facing.

Lastly, there is one last option, to install Ubuntu but make sure you deselect the "format" option. I think you might need to select "something else" and then select the partition to install Ubuntu to which is usually / and then uncheck the box for format this device or make sure the box is unchecked so that it does not format your disk. Of course, make sure to back up any files you want to keep just in case something goes wrong because you might accidentally delete your data!

There is noch such thing as "Ubuntu 22" or "Ubuntu 24". Do you mean "Ubuntu Core 22" and "Ubuntu Core 24"? Those are not meant for end-users! They are meant for developers of embedded devices, IoT devices, that kind of thing, as a starting point for a customized OS for their devices. They can't meaningfully be "updated", you'd have to contact the vendor of the device for a firmware update.
